# Is there a faster way to bulk create Identity users (1M rows) than via userManager.CreateAsync()?

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm working on a new site in ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC that is replacing a Classic ASP existing site.  They have nearly a million users that need to be transferred over to the new site, which is using Entity Framework and Identity Core.
I'm currently creating a list of all the existing users, then in a foreach I'm calling userManager.CreateAsync().  I'm then adding that user to a role (I can do this later in SQL if necessary) using userManager.AddToRoleAsync().
Each run through the foreach is taking approximately 3000-4000 milliseconds, split equally between each of those Async calls, so leaving it running overnight got me 35K imported, which is just not practical.

UPDATE: The good/bad news is that the passwords are currently stored as plain text, so I can bring them in and do the hashing on them, ready for putting into AspNetUsers.  Obviously, this is a Very Bad Way of storing passwords, but makes this current task a bit simpler!

I've looked into writing a stored procedure to call from the code to add the UserName, Email and hashed Password to the AspNetUsers table, but the table needs all the fields and I'm not sure how to generate items such as the id (although I assume it's just a GUID so can be created via NEWID() ), the SecurityStamp and ConcurrencyStamp.

I've removed duplicates by creating a list of all the existing Identity users and adding that in to the Linq query so only non-processed users are processed.  This list building does take time, but just minutes, so that's not really a problem.

I have searched for other posts even slightly related, but none quite answer this specific question.  From that I have at least discovered how to hash the password, so that if I could create a new way of updating the AspNetUsers table directly, but not how to generate the other necessary fields Id, SecurityStamp and ConcurrencyStamp.

Even if I can just find out how to generate the SecurityStamp and ConcurrencyStamp, I can then pass the data to a stored procedure in Entity Framework to add to the AspNetUsers table. (We're using stored procedures in Entity Framework - I know that's not the 'done thing' but the existing codebase is a tapestry of stored procedures that I was unable to unpick!)

```
public async Task<ViewResult> LoadExisting()
    {
        List<ImportModel> existing = new List<ImportModel>();

        var users = userManager.Users.ToList();

        existing = _context.Individual
                    .Where(i => (i.AccessId == 20 && !users.Any(s => s.Email == i.Email) ))
                    .Select(i => new ImportModel { Email = i.Email, Password = i.Password, existingId = i.existingId })
                    .ToList();

        List<string> successes = new List<string>();
        List<string> duplicates = new List<string>();
        List<string> failures = new List<string>();

        IdentityResult result = new IdentityResult();
        IdentityResult roleresult = new IdentityResult();

        foreach (ImportModel indiv in existing)
        {
            var hasher = userManager.PasswordHasher;
            AppUser user = new AppUser
            {
                UserName = indiv.Email,
                Email = indiv.Email,
                Individual_id = indiv.IndividualId
            };
            //indiv.Password = hasher.HashPassword(user, indiv.Password); // this works

            // Do something faster here

            result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, indiv.Password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                // Add to relevant role, set above
                roleresult = await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "ARole");
                successes.Add(indiv.Email + ",");
            }

            else
            {
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    if (error.Code == "DuplicateUserName")
                    {
                        duplicates.Add(indiv.Email + ",");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        failures.Add(indiv.Email + ", <strong>" + error.Code + "</strong>");
                    }
                }                    
            }
        }
        ViewData["LoadExistingSuccesses"] = successes;
        ViewData["LoadExistingDuplicates"] = duplicates;
        ViewData["LoadExistingFailures"] = failures;

        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a layer of abstraction between the UserManager / SigninManager and the backend EF Core `IdentityDbContext`. This abstraction already has a flag to prevent saving changes immediately. Due to the number of generic parameters, accessing this flag is complicated. But it can be done. It would help if this flag was directly configurable in some way.

Setting this flag at runtime is not well tested by the developers of the Identity framework. You may encounter implementation bugs. This work around is dependant on the internals of the Identity framework. It might break between versions.

```cs
    public interface IIdentityAutoSave
    {
        bool AutoSave { get; set; }
    }

    public static class IdentityExtension
    {
        // Why is this so hard??
        public static IdentityBuilder AddSaveHelper(this IdentityBuilder builder)
        {
            var service = builder.Services
                .Where(s => s.ServiceType.IsGenericType && s.ServiceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IUserStore<>))
                .Single();

            var type = service.ImplementationType;
            while(type != null)
            {
                if (type.IsGenericType) {
                    var genericType = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
                    if (genericType == typeof(UserOnlyStore<,,,,,>))
                    {
                        // Implement IIdentityAutoSave with IdentitySaveUser using the same generic parameters
                        builder.Services.AddScoped(
                            typeof(IIdentityAutoSave),
                            typeof(IdentitySaveUser<,,,,,>).MakeGenericType(type.GenericTypeArguments)
                        );
                        return builder;
                    }
                    else if (genericType == typeof(UserStore<,,,,,,,,>))
                    {
                        // Implement IIdentityAutoSave with IdentitySaveUserRole using the same generic parameters
                        builder.Services.AddScoped(
                            typeof(IIdentityAutoSave),
                            typeof(IdentitySaveUserRole<,,,,,,,,>).MakeGenericType(type.GenericTypeArguments)
                        );
                        return builder;
                    }
                }
                type = type.BaseType;
            }
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }

    public class IdentitySaveUser<TUser, TContext, TKey, TUserClaim, TUserLogin, TUserToken> : IIdentityAutoSave
        where TUser : IdentityUser<TKey>
        where TContext : DbContext
        where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
        where TUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<TKey>, new()
        where TUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<TKey>, new()
        where TUserToken : IdentityUserToken<TKey>, new()
    {
        private readonly UserOnlyStore<TUser, TContext, TKey, TUserClaim, TUserLogin, TUserToken> store;
        public IdentitySaveUser(IUserStore<TUser> store)
        {
            this.store = store as UserOnlyStore<TUser, TContext, TKey, TUserClaim, TUserLogin, TUserToken>;
            if (this.store == null)
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
        public bool AutoSave { get { return store.AutoSaveChanges; } set { store.AutoSaveChanges = value; } }
    }

    public class IdentitySaveUserRole<TUser, TRole, TContext, TKey, TUserClaim, TUserRole, TUserLogin, TUserToken, TRoleClaim> : IIdentityAutoSave
        where TUser : IdentityUser<TKey>
        where TRole : IdentityRole<TKey>
        where TContext : DbContext
        where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
        where TUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<TKey>, new()
        where TUserRole : IdentityUserRole<TKey>, new()
        where TUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<TKey>, new()
        where TUserToken : IdentityUserToken<TKey>, new()
        where TRoleClaim : IdentityRoleClaim<TKey>, new()
    {
        private readonly UserStore<TUser, TRole, TContext, TKey, TUserClaim, TUserRole, TUserLogin, TUserToken, TRoleClaim> store;
        private readonly RoleStore<TRole, TContext, TKey, TUserRole, TRoleClaim> roleStore;
        public IdentitySaveUserRole(IUserStore<TUser> store, IRoleStore<TRole> roleStore)
        {
            this.store = store as UserStore<TUser, TRole, TContext, TKey, TUserClaim, TUserRole, TUserLogin, TUserToken, TRoleClaim>;
            this.roleStore = roleStore as RoleStore<TRole, TContext, TKey, TUserRole, TRoleClaim>;
            if (this.store == null || roleStore == null)
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
        public bool AutoSave { get { return store.AutoSaveChanges; } set { store.AutoSaveChanges = roleStore.AutoSaveChanges = value; } }
    }
```

Usage;

```cs
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    ...
        services.AddIdentity...(o => ...)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<Context>()
            .AddSaveHelper();

    ... ControllerAction([FromServices] Context db, [FromServices] UserManager<User> manager, [FromServices] IIdentityAutoSave save){
        // prevent usermanager from saving
        save.AutoSave = false;
        foreach(...) {
            await manager.CreateAsync(...);
        }
        // save all changes at once
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. `UserManager<TUser>.CreateAsync` mostly serves three purposes:

1. It validates the username and password (if provided) to ensure that they conform to the requirements specified in your Identity config.
2. It normalizes the username and email address in separate columns (`NormalizedUserName`/`NormalizedEmail`), so that they can be looked up in a standardized way while still maintaining indexes.
3. If a password is provided, the password will be salted and hashed.

The first two are easy enough to replicate in a bulk insert. The username requirements are pretty straight-forward, and mostly just ensure that's it's URL-safe. As for normalization, as far as I can tell, the `UserName`/`Email` values are simply make all uppercase.

Replicating the password hashing, though, is going to be pretty much impossible. However, it's also not entirely necessary. You can opt to simply force a password reset for every user, which isn't a bad idea, regardless, and it's pretty much unavoidable, anyways, when migrating from one system of authentication to another. Unless you were already being bad and storing plain text passwords, there's no way to know what the users' passwords were in order to migrate them.

Honestly, I wouldn't even bother to try to do this via code. That's going to be the slowest and most difficult approach. Just use something like an SSIS package and literally move the data over via SQL (making modifications as necessary).

Comment: Thanks.  I get what you're saying, but the good/bad news is that the passwords are currently stored as plain text, so I can bring them in and do the hashing on them, ready for putting into Identity.
I'm currently considering adding a new column to the existing user table and putting the hashed password in there, then running a SQL script to fill up the AspNetUsers table, using a guid for id, SecurityStamp and ConcurrencyStamp.

Comment: The problem is not just hashing the password but doing so in exactly the way the app is going to do it. In short, it's not really possible.

Comment: Ok. I'll have to run a few checks but I'd read it's possible using userManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(). I can try this by comparing the hashed password output on a test user.

Comment: If you do that, yes, but you're back to one user at a time.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. Although, I could create the list of existing users, then update all those passwords to their hashes, then bulk update the Aspnet Users somehow,so a three stage thing.